# Select Box to be align right

Tags: html, css

I am using Select box and I want to make My select box to the right Side of the div.. here is my Code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      Some Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
      <select class="selectpicker alibaba" id="graphdate">
         <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
         <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
         <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want it to be? Right side of div is too broad to guess

Comment: Most Right Side of the Div with Col-md-4.

Answer (score 3):

Add some CSS, it's up to you how you reference the select element but the basis is here:

```
select{
    float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/51rhsnwa/

Answer (score 0):

From the row and column layout, I'll assume you're using the Bootstrap Grid layout.

To align an element to the right of **the element that it is a child of**, you can simply add the class `pull-right` to the element in question.

For example, in this case you would change your `<select>` tag to be:

`<select class="selectpicker alibaba pull-right" id="graphdate">`

Answer (score 0):

Add class `pull-right` to your select.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="border:1px solid red;">
      Some Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid blue;">
      <select class="selectpicker alibaba pull-right" id="graphdate">
           <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
           <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
           <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for the reply.. but i have not found anyone's answer helpful. i tried this and it solved my problem

```
<div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2 padding-left-0">
   <select class="selectpicker alibaba" id="graphdate">
     <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
     <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
     <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
   </select>
</div>
```